# Making a variable name to check if it's defined in Python

Tags: python, variables, python-2.7

I have a form where you have the option to add upload inputs. I want the images that will be uploaded with every input to be grouped together (there will be text in between). Every time an upload button is added it get's the name "upload_image1", "upload_image2", ...

I want to check if these names are defined so i can then loop through them later. I am trying to combine upload_image and an integer that is counting up together but it looks like he is trying to add that integer to the value of upload_image which is not defined.

```
if len(form["upload_image1"]) > 0:
    while 1:
        field_count = 1
        if len(form["upload_image" + str(field_count)]) == 0: break
        upload_field = form["upload_image" + str(field_count)]
        upload_image += upload_field
        article_content += """
                            <p>%s</p>
                            """ % (description[field_count].value)
        for item in upload_field:
            article_content += '<img src="http://www.******.com/images/%s/%s">' % (link_title, item.filename)
        field_count = field_count + 1
```

Comment: if form.get("upload_image1",false)...

Comment: you should name your input fields like this: `<input name="upload_image[]" ... /> <input name="upload_image[]" ...  />`, then you will get a nice data structure in `form` that you can easily iterate through.

Comment: What error messages are you getting and when?

Comment: @Pavel I don't understand how you can iterate through this better.

Comment: @pts I am getting a MemoryError, probably because my loop doesn't stop.

Comment: As a first step of fixing the MemoryError, add: `if field_count > 5: break`. Then you may want to `print repr(form)` and try to figure out how to get those form fields. Please also post the output of `print repr(form)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the Memory Error. I accidentally put `field_count = 1` inside my loop so it kept resetting itself.
The rest apparently works just fine. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to avoid the KeyError:

- If `form["upload_image1"]` is a string, then use `form.get("upload_image1", "")` instead.
- If `form["upload_image1"]` is a sequence (e.g. list or tuple), then use `form.get("upload_image1", ())` instead.

Comment: It is a list, but this gives me an Attribute Error.